# WP Bootstrap loader causes many plugins to fail

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, photo-gallery, nextgen-gallery

I am looking for help with what appears to be a WP Bootstrap Loader compatibility problem across many WordPress plugins.  Sadly my developer is super busy and tough to get hold of which I respect but I am trying my hardest to find a way to add some features to my site (using my staging site that I built which is a direct replica of the production site).  Right now I am trying to build a photo gallery using 10web plugin and will also want to use their mailchimp, formmaker and a few other plugins.  Problem is that none of the plugins work, not even other plugins by other developers like NextGen Gallery.  I posted for support here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/10web-photo-gallery-broken-when-using-wp-bootstrap-starter-theme/ and also researched many posts in this group including this one https://wp-customerarea.com/documentation/user-guides/resolving-bootstrap-conflicts/ and none of it is helping.  Any clues and if WP Bootstrapper Loader causes so many conflicts then I have to ask is this the right 'theme' for me and my website if I want to have some independence and less reliability on my already stretched thin but awesome developer?

Installed 'Health Check & Troubleshooting' plugin and checked to see if problem existed with other themes like Kadence and Twenty Twenty-Four and it did not so the problem appears to be a direct conflict between WP Bootstrapper and any other photo gallery plugin I have tried.  Followed instructions here https://wp-customerarea.com/documentation/user-guides/resolving-bootstrap-conflicts/ and was not able to resolve it

Comment: You'll need browser debugging skills to get enough information for us to help you fix this. Conflicts between page-layout frameworks ( of which Bootstrap is one ) and between versions of those frameworks are notoriously hard to resolve.